# Allow all requests to the AKKA-HTTP service

Tags: scala, service, request, akka, akka-http

Comrades!
I have a small service from the AKKA-HTTP example.

```
import ch.megard.akka.http.cors.scaladsl.CorsDirectives._

object Server extends App{
    
    val route = cors() {
      path("hello") {
        get {
          complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "<h1>Привет ёпта</h1>"))
        }
      }
    }

    val routes = cors() {
      concat(route, getUser, createUser, addMessage, getQueue, test, test2)
    }
    
    val bindingFuture = Http().newServerAt("localhost", 8080).bind(routes)
}
```

For CORS i create file resourses/application.conf:

```
akka-http-cors {

  allowed-origins = "*"
  allowed-methods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
}
```

When I run a project in intellij idea, the route works fine:

[image]

But if I run the project in Docker, the route doesn't want to work.
Error in chrome:
[image]

Error in Postman:

[image]

Below are the errors when the project is turned off everywhere:
[image][image]

How do I properly configure the application.conf file so that the application accepts third-party requests? Or maybe the error is hidden in something else?
Please tell me!
I've been thinking for two days.

UPD: File DockerFile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
WORKDIR /opt/docker
ADD --chown=daemon:daemon opt /opt
USER daemon
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/docker/bin/servertelesupp"]
CMD []
```

Project on GitHub: https://github.com/MinorityMeaning/ServerTeleSupp

Comment: CORS does not seem to be the problem. Do you mind adding your Dockerfile code to the question? Plus, please also remove the error images. Check the "How to Ask" guide for more advice on how to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @RodrigoVedovato, Yes, I can delete the error images. But are they really useless? I'll add the contents of the Dockerfile in a minute.

Comment: A text description of the error should be enough for most cases. Images are discouraged except for things that cannot be described using words, like diagrams and rendering issues (like with CSS questions)

Comment: @RodrigoVedovato Here, the guy is facing my situation. https://youtu.be/CzKvO5xO9XE?t=343

Comment: Unless you forgot to mention something else, I believe his problem is different than yours. CORS applies to calls between different domains, like a web page hosted on localhost:4200 calling an API hosted on localhost:8000

Comment: Also, it would be nice if you shared the code for `/opt/docker/bin/servertelesupp`. That way, people can reproduce your example entirely

Comment: Okey, no problem. Load on GitHub.
https://github.com/MinorityMeaning/ServerTeleSupp

Comment: Your Dockerfile doesn't `EXPOSE` any port

Comment: @GaëlJ, I use -p flag in the Docker run string to publish a port.
I believe the problem is with the Cors settings.

Comment: @Mardaunt It's been some time since I used Docker but I believe you still need an `EXPOSE` directive on the Dockerfile, there might be other issues but worth trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`Http().newServerAt("localhost", 8080).bind(routes)`

to

`Http().newServerAt("0.0.0.0", 8080).bind(routes)`

By binding to `localhost` inside docker, you will not be able route traffic from outside to it.

Comment: Yes! Its work for me! Very cool! Thank for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `-p` flag that you are using? It should be `8080:8080` if the server is using 8080 port inside the docker, or `8080:80` if the server is using 80 (and so on). Also please do verify that the port is indeed free inside docker.

PS: I have low reputation and can't add a comment.

Comment: Yes, I'm using 8080:8080
The project uses port 8080.
I'm accessing docker via port 8080.
So I use 8080:8080.